# Explicit formula replication of variance swap using vanilla option under black and scholes model with nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend

Tags: black-scholes, variance-swap

I didn't find the formula for the following portfolio (variance swap replication) with nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend under black and scholes model :

[image] (1)

I found formula and proof only with risk-free rate and dividend equal to zero under black and scholes :

[image] (2)

An explicit formula exist (as (2)) for nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend ? If yes, what is the result ?
(Carr-Madan is not an explicit formula)

Thanks

Comment: $S_t$ and $S_c$ are values of the asset _at different times_. That formula cannot be that of a price, a price is given at a time $c$ for example, if $c<t$. Is it the final payoff of your variance swap?

Comment: See [this](https://www.frouah.com/finance%20notes/Variance%20Swap.pdf).